# Check when a sound finishes playing in Java

Tags: java, audio, addeventlistener, detection, javasound

i'm trying to build my first game in Java: Pacman.
I'm facing the following problem: I'd like the game to freeze while the intro music is playing, so I need to know how to detect it. I was told to use the `LineListener`, I really tried but I couldn't figure out how it works from the Oracle docs...

Here's my GameSounds class:

```
package it.pacman.audio;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.net.URL;


/* This class controls all sound effects*/
public class GameSounds{
    
    Clip nomNom;
    Clip newGame;
    Clip death;
    Clip eatGhost;
    Clip powerPellet;
    /* Keeps track of whether or not the eating sound is playing*/
    boolean stopped, power_pellet;
       

/* Initialize audio files */ 
    public GameSounds(){
        stopped=true; 
        power_pellet=true; 
        URL url;
        AudioInputStream audioIn;
        
        try{
            // Pacman eating sound
            url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sounds/nomnom.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            nomNom = AudioSystem.getClip();
            nomNom.open(audioIn);
            
            // newGame        
            url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sounds/newGame.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            newGame = AudioSystem.getClip();
            newGame.open(audioIn);
            
            // death        
            url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sounds/death.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            death = AudioSystem.getClip();
            death.open(audioIn);

            // eatGhost       
            url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sounds/eatGhost.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            eatGhost = AudioSystem.getClip();
            eatGhost.open(audioIn);
            
            // powerPellet        
            url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sounds/powerPellet.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            powerPellet = AudioSystem.getClip();
            powerPellet.open(audioIn);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    /* Play pacman eating sound */
    public void nomNom(){
        /* If it's already playing, don't start it playing again!*/
        if (!stopped)
          return;

        stopped=false;
        nomNom.stop();
        nomNom.setFramePosition(0);
        nomNom.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    /* Stop pacman eating sound */
    public void nomNomStop(){
        stopped=true;
        nomNom.stop();
        nomNom.setFramePosition(0);
    }
    
    /* Play new game sound */
    public void newGame(){
        newGame.stop();
        newGame.setFramePosition(0);
        newGame.start();
    }
    
    /* Play pacman death sound */
    public void death(){
        death.stop();
        death.setFramePosition(0);
        death.start();
    }

    /* Play eat ghost sound */
    public void eatGhost(){
        eatGhost.stop();
        eatGhost.setFramePosition(0);
        eatGhost.start();
    }

    /* Play power pellet sound */
    public void powerPellet(){
        /* If it's already going, don't start it again!*/
        if (!power_pellet)
          return;

        power_pellet=false;
        powerPellet.stop();
        powerPellet.setFramePosition(0);
        powerPellet.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    /* Stop power pellet sound */
    public void powerPelletStop(){
        power_pellet=true;
        powerPellet.stop();
        powerPellet.setFramePosition(0);
    }

}
```

And here's a chunk of code where I make the game start a new level:

```
   private void initLevel2() {
        sounds.newGame();

        lives = 3;
        level = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < N_BLOCKS * N_BLOCKS; i++) {
            FIRSTMAP[i] = LevelModel.SECONDMAP.getMap()[i];
            screenData[i] = LevelModel.SECONDMAP.getMap()[i];
        }

        continueLevel();
    }
```

Can you please provide a simple example so that I could understand it and implement it? (Even not related to my code) Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a note: You know exactly when the sound starts playing because you trigger it within your code, and you can get the sound length before it starts playing, so you know exactly how long it should run for. So there should be no need for a listener? Use a timer to wait for the sound length, then trigger the next screen/game element to be displayed.

Comment: @sorifiend Your suggestion about calculating lengths is tempting but not generally used. The degree of precision is much higher and more reliable with a line listener. Also, the amount of work required if you decide to alter the length of the cue is also much greater.

Comment: To improve your chances of getting help, I recommend showing us your attempts to *listen* to the end of a single sound asset. As it stands, there's a lot of code pertaining to your project, but that distracts from the question at hand.

Comment: To further the suggestion of @PhilFreihofner, I recommend creating a [mre]. To go the extra length, generate a tone in the source code. A tip on doing that MRE: It only needs one `Clip`. If the code can do the appropriate thing with one clip, it should work for 5 (or 100),